# Excel VBA: how to cast a generic control object into a ComboBox object?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to cast a generic VBA form control object into a ComboBox object so that I can add items to it. The generic object won't allow me to insert items into my existing lists

```
Dim ctlCurrent As MSForms.Control
For Each ctlCurrent In frmItemInput.Controls
    If TypeName(ctlCurrent) = "ComboBox" Then
         Dim lbCurrentComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox
         lbCurrentComboBox = ctlCurrent 'This is where the error occurs, when I try to convert one into another

         ' Adiciona os itens necessários
         lbCurrentComboBox.AddItem ("R")
         lbCurrentComboBox.AddItem ("D")
    End If
Next ctlCurrent
```

My problem is: I have tons of ComboBoxes in my form and I need to add the same options for all of them. So I would like to do this progrmatically.

Comment: henchman has it right.  You need to use Set.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can "cast" an VBA Object by using SET, eg:

```
SET lbCurrentComboBox = ctlCurrent
```

Answer (score 8):

If [phil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2368259/119477) didn't work try

```
SET lbCurrentComboBox = ctlCurrent.Object
```