# How to add events to Controls created at runtime in Excel with VBA

Tags: events, vba, controls

I would like to add a Control and an associated event at runtime in Excel using VBA but I don't know how to add the events.

I tried the code below and the Button is correctly created in my userform but the associated click event that should display the hello message is not working.

Any advice/correction would be welcome.

```
Dim Butn As CommandButton
Set Butn = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
With Butn
    .Name = "CommandButton1"
    .Caption = "Click me to get the Hello Message"
    .Width = 100
    .Top = 10
End With

With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1.CommandButton1").CodeModule
    Line = .CountOfLines
    .InsertLines Line + 1, "Sub CommandButton1_Click()"
    .InsertLines Line + 2, "MsgBox ""Hello!"""
    .InsertLines Line + 3, "End Sub"
End With
UserForm1.Show
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1923457/98422) for a quick intro to using runtime-hooked events in VBA.

Comment: beautifully drafted question. Thanks, had the exact same doubt

Answer (score 30):

The code for adding a button at runtime and then to add events is truly as simple as it is difficult to find out. I can say that because I have spent more time on this perplexity and got irritated more than in anything else I ever programmed.

Create a Userform and put in the following code:

```
Option Explicit


Dim ButArray() As New Class2

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ctlbut As MSForms.CommandButton
    
    Dim butTop As Long, i As Long

    '~~> Decide on the .Top for the 1st TextBox
    butTop = 30

    For i = 1 To 10
        Set ctlbut = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "butTest" & i)

        '~~> Define the TextBox .Top and the .Left property here
        ctlbut.Top = butTop: ctlbut.Left = 50
        ctlbut.Caption = Cells(i, 7).Value
        '~~> Increment the .Top for the next TextBox
        butTop = butTop + 20

        ReDim Preserve ButArray(1 To i)
        Set ButArray(i).butEvents = ctlbut
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Now you need to add a Class Module to your code for the project. Please remember it's class module, not Standard Module.

The Object `butEvents` is the button that was clicked.

Put in the following simple code (in my case the class name is Class2).

---

```
Public WithEvents butEvents As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub butEvents_click()

    MsgBox "Hi Shrey from " & butEvents.Caption

End Sub
```

---

That's it. Now run it!

Comment: Great answer! Easily modified your example for other types of forms!

Comment: I can't seem to get `Me.Controls.Add(...)` to work in Access 2010 Professional with an .mdb file. I'm able to add the `Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library`, but there is no `Add` method for a `Microsoft Access Class Object` Form's Controls (or Control or Form) object in Acc2010, which is tied to the `Me` object. I believe I have to do a `CreateControl` instead, but am still struggling with the details.

Comment: I would like to add that if you work with ActiveX controls and call them by `currCtrl = sheet)"mysheet").OLEObjects.Item(i)` you have to add them to the [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014421/how-to-add-events-to-controls-created-at-runtime-in-excel-with-vba) or [collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994235/handling-events-for-oleobject-commandbuttons-created-at-runtime) by `... = currCtrl.Object` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368252/excel-vba-how-to-cast-a-generic-control-object-into-a-combobox-object).

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Sub AddButtonAndShow()

    Dim Butn As CommandButton
    Dim Line As Long
    Dim objForm As Object

    Set objForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1")

    Set Butn = objForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
    With Butn
        .Name = "CommandButton1"
        .Caption = "Click me to get the Hello Message"
        .Width = 100
        .Top = 10
    End With

    With objForm.CodeModule
        Line = .CountOfLines
        .InsertLines Line + 1, "Sub CommandButton1_Click()"
        .InsertLines Line + 2, "MsgBox ""Hello!"""
        .InsertLines Line + 3, "End Sub"
    End With

    VBA.UserForms.Add(objForm.Name).Show

End Sub
```

This permanently modifies UserForm1 (assuming you save your workbook). If you wanted a temporary userform, then add a new userform instead of setting it to UserForm1. You can then delete the form once you're done with it.

[Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) has some great info about coding the VBE.

Answer (score 4):

DaveShaw, thx for this code man!

I have used it for a togglebutton array (put a 'thumbnail-size' picture called trainer.jpg in the same folder as the excel file for a togglebutton with a picture in it). In the 'click' event the invoker is also available (by the object name as a string)

In the form:

```
Dim CreateTrainerToggleButtonArray() As New ToggleButtonClass 

Private Sub CreateTrainerToggleButton(top As Integer, id As Integer)

Dim pathToPicture As String
pathToPicture = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\trainer.jpg"
Dim idString As String
idString = "TrainerToggleButton" & id

Dim cCont As MSForms.ToggleButton
Set cCont = Me.Controls.Add _
   ("Forms.ToggleButton.1")

With cCont
   .Name = idString
   .Width = 20
   .Height = 20
   .Left = 6
   .top = top
   .picture = LoadPicture(pathToPicture)
   End With

   ReDim Preserve CreateTrainerToggleButtonArray(1 To id)
   Set CreateTrainerToggleButtonArray(id).ToggleButtonEvents = cCont
   CreateTrainerToggleButtonArray(id).ObjectName = idString

   End Sub
```

and a class "ToggleButtonClass"

```
  Public WithEvents ToggleButtonEvents As MSForms.ToggleButton
  Public ObjectName As String


  Private Sub ToggleButtonEvents_click()
  MsgBox "DaveShaw is the man... <3 from your friend: " & ObjectName
  End Sub
```

Now just simple call from UserForm_Initialize

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   Dim index As Integer
   For index = 1 To 10
     Call CreateTrainerToggleButton(100 + (25 * index), index)
   Next index
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to do it:

1 - Insert a class module and write this code:

```
Public WithEvents ChkEvents As MSForms.CommandButton
Private Sub ChkEvents_click()
MsgBox ("Click Event")
End Sub
```

2 - Insert a userform and write this code:

```
Dim Chk As New Clase1
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim NewCheck As MSForms.CommandButton
Set NewCheck = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
NewCheck.Caption = "Prueba"
Set Chk.ChkEvents = NewCheck
End Sub
```

Now show the form and click the button

Answer (score 2):

This was my solution to add a commandbutton and code without using classes
It adds a reference to allow access to vbide
Adds the button

Then writes a function to handle the click event in the worksheet

```vb
Sub AddButton()
Call addref
Set rng = DestSh.Range("B" & x + 3)
'Set btn = DestSh.Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)
Set myButton = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Left:=rng.Left, Top:=rng.Top, Height:=rng.Height * 3, Width:=rng.Width * 3)
DoEvents
With myButton
     '.Placement = XlPlacement.xlFreeFloating
     .Object.Caption = "Export"
     .Name = "BtnExport"

     .Object.PicturePosition = 1
     .Object.Font.Size = 14
   End With
   Stop
   myButton.Object.Picture = LoadPicture("F:\Finalised reports\Templates\Macros\evolution48.bmp")

Call CreateButtonEvent

End Sub

Sub addref()
On Error Resume Next
Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB"
Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB"

End Sub


    Private Sub CreateButtonEvent()
On Error GoTo errtrap

    Dim oXl As Application: Set oXl = Application
    oXl.EnableEvents = False
    oXl.DisplayAlerts = False
    oXl.ScreenUpdating = False
    oXl.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False

    Dim oWs As Worksheet
    Dim oVBproj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim oVBcomp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim oVBmod As VBIDE.CodeModule '
    Dim lLine As Single
    Const QUOTE As String = """"

    Set oWs = Sheets("Contingency")
    Set oVBproj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
    Set oVBcomp = oVBproj.VBComponents(oWs.CodeName)
    Set oVBmod = oVBcomp.CodeModule

    With oVBmod
        lLine = .CreateEventProc("Click", "BtnExport") + 1
        .InsertLines lLine, "Call CSVFile"
    End With

    oXl.EnableEvents = True
    oXl.DisplayAlerts = True
Exit Sub
errtrap:


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the code needs to be added to the Userform, not to the button itself.

So something like

```
With UserForm1.CodeModule
  'Insert code here
End With
```

In place of your `With ThisWorkbook`

Answer (score 0):

Because of UserForm is Object module, You can use it without supplement class. The UserForm code is:

```
Public WithEvents CustomBtn As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim MyCmd As MSForms.CommandButton

    Set MyCmd = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "MyCmd", True)
    MyCmd.Top = 60
    MyCmd.Left = 100
    MyCmd.Caption = "My Button"

    Set CustomBtn = MyCmd
End Sub

Private Sub CustomBtn_Click()
    MsgBox "Hello from " & CustomBtn.Caption
End Sub
```