# VBA name of CommandButton?

Tags: vba, excel, commandbutton

The following code succesfully creates a commandbutton in the initialisation of a form:

```
create button
        Dim Obj As Object
        Set Obj = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "commandbuttondone", True)
        With Obj
            .Caption = "filled in"
            .Left = 550
            .Height = 40
            .Width = 35
            .Top = 5
        End With
```

I think the above created commandbutton is named: "commandbuttondone", and when it is clicked I want it to do something, so in the code for the sheet, I created a sub:

```
Private Sub commandbuttondone_Click()
'Private Sub commandbutton_Click()
'Private Sub commandbutton1_Click()
'Sub commandbuttondone_Click()
'Sub commandbutton_Click()
'Sub commandbutton1_Click()


MsgBox (nr_of_zeros)

For test1 = 1 To nr_of_zeros + 1 'create textboxes
    Dim ctrl            As Control
    Dim absorb_text     As String

    ' stack suggestion:
    ' loop through all control in user form
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        ' check if control is type TextBox
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
            ' if control name is 1 (first created TextBox in your array)
            If ctrl.name = "1" Then
                absorb_text = ctrl.Text

                'the message box is for debug only
                MsgBox absorb_text
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl
Next test1

End Sub
```

And nothing happens, not even the `msgbox(nr_of_zeros)`. What don't I comprehend in this matter? Does the form not allow a msgbox to pop up, or did I get the name wrong?

Comment: I believe you have simply added an object to a form. I don't think it is going to have events.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/3014421/293078. John Walkenbach used to have an excellent page on this, but I can't find it now.

Comment: @Maximilian brutus III you are confusing adding a `CommandButton` and the answer I gave to your previus post regarding an array of `TextBox`es. What are you trying to achieve now ? You want the `MsgBox` to popup once someone clicks on the Run-time created `CommandButton` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado yes, I tried to extrapolate your method/syntax to an analog XYproblem of generating an action as a result of a dynamically created `CommandButton`. I solved it by temporarily using a static `CommandButton` which responds fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the `CommandButton` at run-time with setting by defining a variable with `Dim Cb As MSForms.CommandButton` , and then later set it with `Set Cb = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "commandbuttondone", True)` , this will set-up a new Command-button named "commandbuttondone" to your `User_Form1`.

Then once you click on it, use the code below just to display a message box with the Command button's name:

**"commandbuttondone" code**:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub commandbuttondone_Click()

Dim CBctrl              As Control
Dim absorb_text         As String

' loop through all control in user form
For Each CBctrl In Me.Controls
    ' check if control is type Command button
    If TypeName(CBctrl) = "CommandButton" Then
        ' if control name is "commandbuttondone"
        If CBctrl.Name = "commandbuttondone" Then
            absorb_text = CBctrl.Name

            'the message box is for debug only
            MsgBox absorb_text
        End If
    End If
Next CBctrl

End Sub
```