# Can't add events to dynamically created buttons in VBA userform

Tags: vba, excel

Simply put, I've tried following the example found here : [How to add events to Controls created at runtime in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014421/how-to-add-events-to-controls-created-at-runtime-in-excel-with-vba) but when I click my button nothing happens.

The thing is that I don't create lots of buttons at once, a new button is added everytime the user clicks a certain pre added button.

Code for the button creation :

```
'Finally the delete button
Dim newb As MSForms.CommandButton
'thisQuant is a var keeping track of how many buttons there are
Set newb = FProducts.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "del" & thisQuant, False)
Dim Button As New Class1
Set Button.delButton = newb
```

And the new Class as stated in the example :

```
Public WithEvents delButton As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub delButton_Click()
    MsgBox "test"
    'quantProd = CInt(NewNota.ProductQuant.Caption)
End Sub
```

I come from python and VBA is extremely confusing.

Comment: probably you should show more of your code in a [mcve]. THe other solution should work, so your first approach should be to copy / implement that *exactly* as-is, and see if that works. Do that in a new workbook if needed. I notice that in the other solution, it's creating a button *array* in the form's constructor: `Dim ButArray() As New Class2` (where `Class2` is the class module for your button event class. I seem to recall you need to keep these buttons all in memory like that. Haven't tested this in a long time though.

Comment: Most common problem doing this is forgetting to declare your Class1 instance as Global (ie. at the top of the module, not in a Sub or Function), so it goes out of scope and is destroyed as soon as the code creating the button exits.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yup, that was it, thanks man. I just now realized you can make declarations in a module. If you want to post a full answer I will rep you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common mistake made when doing this type of thing is forgetting to declare your Class1 instance - or your array/collection of instances - as Global (ie. at the top of the module, not in a Sub or Function).

If you don't do this then your custom class instance goes out of scope and is destroyed as soon as the code creating the button exits.

```
Dim Button As Class1

Sub CreateButton()
    Dim newb As MSForms.CommandButton

    '...

    'thisQuant is a var keeping track of how many buttons there are
    Set newb = FProducts.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "del" & thisQuant, False)

    Set Button = New Class1
    Set Button.delButton = newb

    '...

End Sub
```