# How to determine if textbox inside userform1 was clicked? and get its value so I can do msgbox then display the text?

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm not sure if this is doable or not.
I'm trying to get the value of an input box in my userform and display it in a MsgBox during the time that it was focused  or clicked.

Is there a way to do this?

Say I have Textbox1 with a value of `Apple` and when I click that TextBox1 
MsgBox will appear that will display the value of my TextBox1 which is `Apple`.

Note: I have a lot of TextBox so I'm not only referring to TextBox1.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.controls.textbox_events(v=vs.120).aspx). There are many Events that you can use: Click, Change, Exit, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the `TextBox1_Enter()` event (when the text box is entered) or the `TextBox1_MouseUp` event (when the text box is clicked) to trigger a message box and you will have to do this for each Textbox.

But you can use procedure:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ShowMyMsgBog(Value As String)
    MsgBox Value
End Sub

'you need one event for each TextBox
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    ShowMyMsgBog TextBox1
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Enter()
    ShowMyMsgBog TextBox2
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi I can't see code: 'Private Sub ShowMyMsgBog(Value As String)
    MsgBox Value
End Sub" working.

Comment: is there a way to loop the Message box Enter?
my Message box varies on the number of rows that has value on my cells

Comment: (1) I did not understand your first comment. If it is "not working" tell what error message you get. (2) No you need one event for each TextBox there is no shorter way. (3) I think my code does exactly what you described in your question. If not then you question was asked bad.

Comment: I mean I copied your first code that determine if I click my textBox and no error but also no result. It did not show up MsgBox

Comment: My TextBox is under a userform

Comment: (1) Of course you need both to get it work. The `ShowMyMsgBog` **and** `TextBox1_Enter` is needed to show a messagebox! And for more TextBoxes you need a `_Enter` for each TextBox. (2) "*My TextBox is under a userform*" that's nice but doesn't change anything.

Comment: Will review this code ,  also did not work in my side. 
I have my textbox created by below method

Comment: Set box = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", row.row & colIndex)

Comment: I copied your code and don't give me the result. can you give me a sample file ?

Comment: So why didn't you tell us that you dynamically added the textboxes? That's of course a completely different approach! But this was already solved here: [How to add events to Controls created at runtime in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014421/how-to-add-events-to-controls-created-at-runtime-in-excel-with-vba). So have a look there.

Comment: Thanks for that link will go back once I solve the problem using that reference its been 2 days searching for a solution . thanks bro.