# How do you dynamically set the event handler of form controls in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

This is what I have so far, from what I've gather from how others accomplished it.

```
Set iComboBoxes = New Collection
'Cycling through all controls and gathering all comboboxes
For Each CTRL In UserForm1.Controls
    If TypeName(CTRL) = "ComboBox" Then
        iComboBoxes.Add CTRL
        'Setting onmousedown event handler
        CTRL.OnMouseDown = "=AllComboBoxes_MouseDown(" & CTRL.Name & ")"
    End If
Next CTRL
```

I get an error saying that the object doesn't support this property or method, on the line where I set the OnMouseDown event handler. I've seen other people do it like this, so I must be missing something.

Comment: Where have you seen other people do that? In Access?

Comment: @Rory Yes, and from what I could tell, the property is the same in Excel according to the documentation. I couldn't see any differences.

Comment: The difference is that that doesn't work! You need to use a custom class and `WithEvents` variable(s). There are numerous examples on here (and elsewhere).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add events to Controls created at runtime in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014421/how-to-add-events-to-controls-created-at-runtime-in-excel-with-vba)