# Access VBA (2016). Creating Controls with events at runtime

Tags: vba, ms-access, events, runtime

I'm trying to create CheckBoxes with events at runtime.

*(Reason:  I want to display a crosstab query for editing.  Since this can't be done I want to make the values (all Boolean) invert when they are clicked programmatically.)*

My code creates the controls no problem but won't run because of a compile error when the class is instantiated.  "**Application-defined or object-defined error."**

(My starting point for the class structure came from [How to add events to Controls created at runtime in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014421/how-to-add-events-to-controls-created-at-runtime-in-excel-with-vba#8986622) but I think this is sufficiently different to warrant a new thread.)

```
Me.Sub_FilterVal_Populate.Form.RecordSource = "FilterValsCrosstab" ' Renewing with the same dataset does seem to cause a requery/refresh

Dim ColNum As Integer
Dim ColName As String
Dim ColWid As Integer
Dim ColMax As Integer
Dim CurrentX  As Integer
Dim ctlLabel As Control
Dim ctlChk As Control
Dim CheckArray() As New Class1
CurrentX = 3500
ColWid = 1400

'  ######################   Close any existing example of the sub form without saving
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Sub_Test", acSaveNo
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

'  ######################    Open a fresh copy of the prototype form
DoCmd.OpenForm "Sub_Test", acDesign
ColMax = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("FilterValsCrossTab").Fields.Count - 1
'   ######################   Loop through to create each column checkbox and column header
For ColNum = 2 To ColMax
    ColName = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("FilterValsCrossTab").Fields(ColNum).Name
    Set ctlChk = CreateControl("Sub_Test", acCheckBox, acDetail, , ColName, CurrentX, 1, ColWid, 300) 'Note: Can't edit CrossTabs
        ReDim Preserve CheckArray(1 To ColNum)   ' ######################   Now need to save as New Class with extra events
        Set CheckArray(ColNum).CheckEvents = ctlChk 'FALLS OVER HERE
     Set ctlLabel = CreateControl("Sub_Test", acLabel, acHeader, , ColName, CurrentX, 1, ColWid, 800)  ' Can't name parent in hedaer
        CurrentX = CurrentX + ColWid + 20
    ctlLabel.Caption = ColName
Next
RunCommand acCmdFormView
```

My Class1 object looks like this

```
Option Compare Database
Public WithEvents CheckEvents As Access.CheckBox

Public Sub CheckEvents_GotFocus()
   MsgBox "GotFocus!", vbOKOnly, "CheckBox Event"
End Sub
```

Comment: You can onyly add controls in design view. These controls are "design-time instances" and they differ from runtime instances. To add a Class1 instance for every runtime-checkbox, you can use code that is executed at runtime (Load event of their parent form). Unfortunately, when these checkboxes are bound to fields of a recordset that isn't updateable, non of their events fire. Using unbound controls also isn't an option, because they display the same value in every row. As a workaround, you could place transparent buttons in front of the checkboxes and add these to the WithEvents variable.

Comment: ... btw, your array variable should be placed in a standard module (at the module level), because otherwise it gets destroyed when your procedure finishes (or in the form that contains the checkboxes at the form level).

Comment: Also: Supposed that you add code that reacts on the checkbox (or transparent button) click event and then requery the form (which will execute the crosstab query again), what will happen if that column isn't contained in the crosstab query result anymore?

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER:** I highly recommend you don't take this approach, but instead dynamically bind fields to precreated checkboxes and hide unused controls, since that will keep you from switching back and forth to design view, requiring your database to be recompiled. Recompiling your database while running code can cause a state loss leading to all kinds of problems.

---

**Answer:** The problem of most likely is that controls in design view don't behave the same as controls in form view. To set that *CheckEvents* check box, you need to set it equal to a check box in form view, not one in design view. You also can't store the controls you're creating in design view to re-use when you've switched the form to form view, because they're cleared as soon as it switches.

To work around this, you can create a collection of control names, and then set the event handlers for these controls after the form switched to form view.

```
Dim collControlNames As New Collection
DoCmd.OpenForm "Sub_Test", acDesign
ColMax = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("FilterValsCrossTab").Fields.Count - 1
'   ######################   Loop through to create each column checkbox and column header
For ColNum = 2 To ColMax
    ColName = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("FilterValsCrossTab").Fields(ColNum).Name
    Set ctlChk = CreateControl("Sub_Test", acCheckBox, acDetail, , ColName, CurrentX, 1, ColWid, 300) 'Note: Can't edit CrossTabs
        ctlChk.OnGotFocus = "[Event Procedure]" 'Required to get the control to send events
        collControlNames.Add ctlChk.Name
     Set ctlLabel = CreateControl("Sub_Test", acLabel, acHeader, , ColName, CurrentX, 1, ColWid, 800)  ' Can't name parent in hedaer
        CurrentX = CurrentX + ColWid + 20
    ctlLabel.Caption = ColName
Next
RunCommand acCmdFormView
Dim l As Long
ReDim CheckArray(1 To collControlNames.Count) 'No need to redim preserve, array is empty
For l = 1 To collControlNames.Count
    Set CheckArray(l) = Forms!Sub_test.Controls(collControlNames(l)) 'Set the controls
Next
```

There are several challenges you haven't tackled yet, judging by your code. For one, `CheckArray` should be defined somewhere it persists (e.g. in a module outside of any sub).