# Adding event macro on multiple generated userform controls

Tags: excel, vba, userform

How to make the relatively same event code to multiple generated userform controls?

I have made a userform [pre-start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKFI4.png) that creates command buttons off a list from another sheet [after initialize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTUJD.png). The idea right now is to put the stored caption of the userform control I click on the active cell. Right now I can only add a event sub on the one that is already on the userform. How can I add the same event code that I applied to every command button that is generated? Here is the code so far, including the click event sub:

```
Option Explicit

Dim Genre(0 To 20) As msforms.CommandButton

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Genre(0 To 20) As msforms.CommandButton
    i = 0
    
    Do
        Set Genre(i) = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
        With Genre(i)
                .Width = Me.Controls("Unknown").Width
                .Height = Me.Controls("Unknown").Height
                .Left = Me.Controls("Unknown").Left
                .Top = Me.Controls("Unknown").Top + Me.Controls("Unknown").Height * (i + 1)
                .Caption = Worksheets("Button Data Sheet").Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value
        End With
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until Worksheets("Button Data Sheet").Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value = ""
    
End Sub

Private Sub Unknown_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = Me.Unknown.Caption
End Sub
```

Thank you very much!

---

EDIT followup question. Thank you chris nielsen for the even class module. But now I have trouble trying to refer which command button did I press as I need the button's caption to put on the active cell. I cannot use Userform1. because the command button is not generated yet.

Here is the code for the userform.

```
Option Explicit

Dim GenreArray() As New Class1
Dim Genre(0 To 20) As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Do
        Set Genre(i) = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
        With Genre(i)
                .Width = Me.Controls("Unknown").Width
                .Height = Me.Controls("Unknown").Height
                .Left = Me.Controls("Unknown").Left
                .Top = Me.Controls("Unknown").Top + Me.Controls("Unknown").Height * (i + 1)
                .Caption = Worksheets("Button Data Sheet").Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value
        End With
        
        ReDim Preserve GenreArray(0 To i)
        Set GenreArray(i).clickEvent = Genre(i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until Worksheets("Button Data Sheet").Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value = ""
    
End Sub

Private Sub Unknown_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = Me.Unknown.Caption
End Sub
```

Here is the code for the class module.

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents clickEvent As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub clickEvent_click()

    ActiveCell.Value = UserForm1.Unknown.Caption

End Sub
```

Comment: Be sure to use the [event class method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8986622)

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thank you but I have a followup question. Now that it has successfully go refer to the class module sub, how can I make the class module refer to the button' caption that I clicked? the Me. does not work anymore and I realized that I need to make that script dynamic as well. Off the event class module link you sent, it only has a generic msgbox command that won't refer to the command button clicked.

Comment: In the event class the object `clickEvent` is the button that was clicked. In this context it has a limited set of properties.  Use `Private Sub clickEvent_click()
    ActiveCell.Value = clickEvent.Caption
End Sub`