# TreeView appears as CustomControl - cannot re-cast to TreeView

Tags: vba, ms-access, casting, treeview

I have a `TreeView` in a form (specifically `Microsoft TreeView Control, version 6.0`), and whilst it doesn't play so nicely with the VBE's Intellisense, I'm able to use all its properties, functions, etc.

Unfortunately, I seem unable to do this:

```
Dim tvw As TreeView
Set tvw = Me.MyTreeView 'The control on the form
```

I get a type mismatch error. So I fired up the Immediate window and had a look at the type of my form's TreeView:

```
? TypeName(Me.MyTreeView)
CustomControl
```

It seems that, for whatever reason, VBA is treating my `TreeView` object as a `CustomControl` object.

How can I convert `CustomControl` back to `TreeView` (or make VBA treat it as a 'TreeView' in the first place)? Type casting doesn't seem to exist in VBA (at least, VB's `CType` function does not work). I'm writing a wrapper class for the TreeView, so just treating it as a `CustomControl` won't work, as I need access to `Treeview`'s events, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more digging, this [answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10145798/2061621) seems to have worked:

```
Dim tvw As TreeView
Set tvw = Me.MyTreeView.Object
```