# VBA: Assign a generic OLEObject to a CheckBox variable

Tags: vba, checkbox, activex, controls, ole

My code loops through all of the existing OLEObjects within the current sheet in an Excel workbook. I want it to find a specific one (based on the name passed to the sub) which is **always** a CheckBox and assign it to a variable of type CheckBox.

*Note: The other objects are not all Checkboxes, hence the generic OLEObject type.*

Example code that calls sub, showing example of name:

```
HandleCheckBoxClick("chkAddSummary")
```

Sub that looks for this specific object:

```
Sub HandleCheckBoxClick(nm As String)

    Dim o As OLEObject
    Dim cb As CheckBox

    For Each o In Me.OLEObjects
        If o.name = nm Then
            Set cb = o
        End If
    Next o

End Sub
```

I found a very similar question at: [Excel VBA: how to cast a generic control object into a ComboBox object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368252/excel-vba-how-to-cast-a-generic-control-object-into-a-combobox-object) but it refers to Form Controls (not ActiveX Controls). I tried the method given in the answer to see whether it was transferrable between the two control types but had no success.

The reason I want to do this is similar to the asker of the question I refer to - I cannot use methods like CheckBox.Value with a generic OLEObject variable.

I have also tried using the OLEObject.progID method to make sure `o` is a checkbox object. The error I get when trying to `Set cb = o` is a Type Mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When declared as `MSForms.CheckBox` it then should be possible to assign `o.Object`.

```
Sub test()
    HandleCheckBoxClick "chkAddSummary"
End Sub

Sub HandleCheckBoxClick(nm As String)

    Dim o As OLEObject
    Dim CB As MSForms.CheckBox

    For Each o In Me.OLEObjects
        If o.Name = nm Then
            Set CB = o.Object
        End If
    Next o

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find (so far) how to assign it to a `CheckBox`, I found how to assign it to a `OLEObject` variable (if that helps you).

```
Sub HandleCheckBoxClick(nm As String)

Dim o           As OLEObject
Dim CB          As CheckBox
Dim oleObj      As OLEObject

' loop though all OLEObjects in "Sheet2" >> modify to your sheet name
For Each o In Sheets("Sheet2").OLEObjects
    If TypeName(o.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
        Debug.Print o.Name

        ' if you have more then 1 CheckBox
        If o.Name = nm Then
            Set oleObj = o
'            Set CB = o.Select
        End If
    End If
Next o

' just to test the options with OLEObject variable
With t
    t.Top = 100
    If t.Object.Value = True Then
        MsgBox "CheckBoX " & nm & " is selected"
    Else
        MsgBox "CheckBoX " & nm & " is not selected"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to get the checkbox state

```
Dim checkBox1 As Object
Set checkBox1 = Sheet1.OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object
MsgBox checkBox1.Value
```